# Why FFTW3's DST Type-1 (discrete sine transform) function is slow?

Tags: c++, c, fft, discrete-mathematics, fftw

I used fftw3 s FFTW_RODFT00 function, but it's very slow (as they mentioned in documents. [fftw3 2.5.2 Real even/odd DFTs](https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Real-even_002fodd-DFTs-_0028cosine_002fsine-transforms_0029.html)).

```
// N->Array length, input->Input Array, output->Output Array
fftw_plan plan = fftw3_r2r_1d(N, input, output, FFTW_RODFT, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

fftw_execute(plan);

//using output...

fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
fftw_cleanup();
```

I tried to convert dst function manually but it O(n^2) algorithms so it's slow either.

How can i calculate fast discrete sine transfrom with using FFT algorithm, not using DST Type-1 Funciton?

Comment: Not quite an answer to your question, but if you're unhappy with FFTW3, you might take a look at [this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/ipp.html#gs.rfeld7)

Comment: Did you compile FFTW yourself?  If so, how did you compile it, including all compilation options?

Comment: @PaulSanders thanks for your answer. I will review the page.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm not sure i fully understand your question. But i did similar steps in this video.

Comment: [Video Link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geYbCA137PU&ab_channel=DamianDZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to calculate Discrete Sine Transform with FFTW3's FFT library function. **But i should say it still slower than MATLAB dst() function (and i still don't know why)**. Let me simply explain what i did:

```
//x->Your first array with some values
//y->FFT input array
//z->FFT output array
//n->First array(x) size

#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1

function_Name(){
const int n = 1000;
double x[n][2];

//Fill x with some value
for(i){
x[i][REAL]=i+1;
x[i][IMAG]=0;
}

fftw_complex y[(n+1)*2];
fftw_complex z[(n+1)*2];

y[0][REAL]=0;
y[0][IMAG]=0;

for(){
//Add x to y from 2. element(y[1])
}

y[n+1][REAL]=0;
y[n+1][IMAG]=0;

for(){
//Invert x and multiply by "-" and add to y
}

fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d((n+1)*2, y, z, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

fftw_execute(plan);

**//You can use z but first you have to Invert (fliplr in MATLAB) it and take only first n elements and only IMAG parts.**

fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
fftw_cleanup();

}
```

I know this algorithm isn't perfect but I'm working on it to speed up and to make a clean. For speed difference between MATLAB fft() function and FFTW's FFT function is still a problem. I will open a new question about it.

Comment: It would pay to keep the plan kicking around, if you intend to use it more than once.  As for FFTW being slower than matlab, well, a lot of smart folks have put a lot of effort into both, but perhaps the matlab folks are smarter...